# Is there a way to switch to "su -" after switching users through "su"?

Tags: shell, login, su

Basically what I want to be able to do is to switch to having used "su -" instead of the traditional hyphenless "su" after already using "su" to switch to another account.

My initial thought was to do another "su -" but that sounded a bit silly, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Couldn't you un-`su` and then `su -`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run the user's shell profile like this:

```
. ~/.profile
```

That's a dot, space, tilde, slash, dot, then the word **profile**

You can read about profile [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.baseadmn/doc/baseadmndita/prof_file.htm).

Answer (score 2):

You can start a subshell as login shell, e.g. `bash -l`.

Answer (score 0):

you're right, there's nothing that keeps you from just doing `su -User2` and ending up with something like User1->root->User2. You can also just type `exit` to end the "su" session and drop back down to User1 and then type `su -User2`

Comment: FYI, some implementations of `su` require a space between the `-` and the username.